# Laravel 7 multiple auth roles

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, roles, laravel-7

I am attempting to make custom auth roles for a site, i have followed another stack overflow post that seems to get it working but mine always fails, i know the information exists since im dumping and dying the information to screen once Auth::guard fails. The problem is that even though the information exists auth guard fails

```
if (Auth::guard('Admin')->attempt(['Username' => $Request->input('UName'), 'Password' => $Request->input('Password')]))
```

The information is validated and approved and manages to pass

```
 if (Admins::where('Username', $Request->input('UName'))->exists()) {
            $AdminDetails = Admins::Where('Username', $Request->input('UName'))->first();
            if(Hash::check($Request->input('Password'), $AdminDetails->Password)){
                   //user details are correct
            }
  }
```

I have made the authenticatable for both the user and the admin the code above attempts to authorize the admin, i have also changed the config/auth.php file as shown below

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'Admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'Admin',
        ],
        'User' => [
            'driver' => 'session', 
            'provider' => 'User',
        ],
    ],
```

```
'providers' => [
        'User' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'Admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admins::class,
        ]

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

The models are within the correct namespace as shown below with the admin authenticatable

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Admins extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'Admin';

    protected $fillable = [
        'FName', 'LName', 'Email', 'Password', 'Username'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];
}
```

and the user authenticatable

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Users extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'User';

    protected $fillable = [
        'FullName', 'Email', 'CompanyName','ReferedBy','PhoneNumber','MemberStatus','CustomMessage',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Laravel 7 displays no errors or anything but the if stament that attempts to log the user in fails

Also the migration for the Admin Model is

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Username');
            $table->string('FName');
            $table->string('LName');
            $table->string('Email');
            $table->string('Password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

I am aware this is a lot of information to put in a single question but i know that its all relevant to the problem.
Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing an array of credentials to `Auth::attempt` the element that holds the password **MUST** be named `password`, it has no relation to any field name on the table. This is how the User Provider knows which field is supposed to be the "password" since it needs to do a hash check; every other field except `password` in the credentials are WHERE conditions of a query.

```
['Username' => ..., 'password' => ...]
```

If your Model/table is using a different field for the password besides `password` you will have to tell the model this by defining the `getAuthPassword` method:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->Password;
}
```

Comment: The model is using Password instead of password so if i change the p to lower case the problem will be fixed?

Comment: if you change the field of the table to `password` and you adjust the credentials array, then you will not have to define the `getAuthPassword` method yourself as it will be using the default which is the `password` field

Comment: Thanks is this common in Laravel or is this an exception. Either way i will start using lower case letters, thanks for your help.

Comment: you can name the fields what you want, but if that particular field isn't `password` you have to let the auth system know this as by default `getAuthPassword` returns the value of the `password` field ... but yes its common to have fields with lowercase